# How jQuery selector elements are also jQuery objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am building a really tiny library/framework as part of my journey to understand jQuery and how its core works.

I am wondering how jQuery selector elements are also returned as jQuery object and have all the methods of the jQuery. For example:

`$('ul li').each(function(){
   console.log($(this));
})`

The $(this) is reference to the jQuery object for DOM element *<li>* and has all the methods of jQuery.

The log shows this:

`[li, context: li, jquery: "2.1.0", constructor: function, selector: "", toArray: function…]
0: li
context: li
length: 1
__proto__: Object[0]`

Here is a small part of the lib illustrating how I handle the initialisation and the `each` method.

```
(function( global, factory ) {factory( global );}
    (window, function( window ) {
        var document = window.document;
        var LibInit = function( selector ) {
            return new Lib( selector );
        };
        function Lib ( selector ) {
            this.selector = selector;
            return this;
        }
        Lib.prototype = {
            each: function(stack, callback) {
                var i;
                for ( i in stack ) {
                    if ( typeof stack[i] === 'object' )
                        callback(i, stack[i]);
                }
                return this;
            }
        }
        window.Lib = LibInit;
    }
));

Lib().each(document.querySelectorAll('ul li'), function(i,v){
    console.log(v);
})
```

This Lib each returns the direct DOM object for the specific element.
How can I change it to return the DOM object wrapped with the object of Lib.

I am sorry for the complicated explanation, just can't think out a better way to explain it.

Also a side question. How console.log of $/jQuery returns string for the init function and $.plugin returns a method from the prototype. Basically there is no prototype of $ because the $ is reference to NOT instantiated function/object.

Comment: `callback(i, $(stack[i]));`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 for ( i in stack ) {
     if ( typeof stack[i] === 'object' )
         callback(i, new Lib(stack[i]));
     }
 }
```

Comment: How come I didn't think about this... Thanks! Also any idea about the side question? Or I should post it as separate question